# How to select table parameters in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, plsql

I have table EMPLOYEES, I need to export ALL table parameters (pctfree, pctused etc.) at a time
How can I do this without using many expressions like

`SELECT PCT_FREE FROM EMPLOYEES;`

Comment: What are you planning on doing with that information? (there might already be tools/procedures that do what you want.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE','EMPLOYEES') from dual;